# Cassandra as Database for Role Based Access Control System

Tags: cassandra

I would like to know your opinion about using Cassandra to implement a
RBAC-like authentication & authorization model. We have simplified the
central relationship of the general model
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) to:

user ---n:m--- role ---n:m--- resource

user(s) and resource(s) are indexed with externally visible identifiers.
These identifiers need to be "re-ownable" (think: mail aliases), too.

The main reason to consider Cassandra is the availability, scalability
and (global) geo-redundancy. This is hard to achieve with a RBDMS.

On the other side, RBAC has many m:n relations. While some
inconsistencies may be acceptable, resource ownership (i.e. role=owner)
must never ever be mixed up.

What do you think? Is such relational model an antipattern for Cassandra
usage? Do you know similar solutions based on Cassandra?

Comment: Two immediate questions come to mind when evaluating Cassandra, before getting into RDBMS vs. NoSQL. 1) How big a dataset are you going to be dealing with? 2) How often and how fast will you be adding data to it? For instance, you're starting with 1TB dataset and will be adding 10GB of data per day. If you have a smaller set of data and it won't be growing much, I think a RDBMS would offer more power for the m:n relationships without having to do extra work.

Comment: If you don't have lots of writes going through, I'd lean towards an RDBMS with a hot backup for implementing the security. Reason being you can use indexes to speed up the reads in the RDBMS and you'll get the ability to do the m:n relationships without having to code a ton of column families to handle it all. You'll also ensure you have no inconsistencies--something I think you'd want when implementing a security architecture.

Comment: about 100.000.000 accounts. Not heavy write load, but lots of reads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and turn my comments into an answer so they're in one place.

While you have a large sounding dataset, 100,000,000 accounts to manage if I'm reading that correctly, you also have the constraint of needing to enforce some level of consistency to ensure a specific relationship never falls out of sync. You also have a situation with lots of  one-to-many relationships (resource-->users or m:n from above) that you need to enforce. Additionally, it sounds like you will be reading from the dataset more than writing to it. Subsequently, I think an RDBMS with a hot backup would solve your problems better than a custom Cassandra deployment. 
The reasons behind this being:

1. One-To-Many relationships in RDBMS can be expressed as a SQL statement that joins across tables and you only have to store the data once. In Cassandra, depending on the setup, you'd have to store the same information in multiple places to properly reflect the relationships. This would lead to a rather messy and redundant data model.
2. Consistency -- Cassandra is eventually consistent, which is fine when dealing with most kinds of data, IMHO. However, when dealing with something like security, which necessitates consistency at all times, RDBMSes (plural?) have a significant advantage in Transactions to ensure you're data is always in sync. Something I think is important from a security perspective.
3. Read Speed -- Using indexes in RDBMS will significantly speed up reading out of the DB, so I wouldn't make this a driving decision factor until you can empirically determine will be a significant bottleneck. Cassandra's quorum reading model could, in some ways, be slower, as you have to wait on N machines (where N >= 1) to return an answer and correct that answer if it's out of sync.
4. Redundancy -- An RDBMS with a hot backup (master-master copying) would solve redundancy problems.

Cassandra's a great tool and I enjoy using, however, in this case, I think your model works better with a RDBMS than it does with Cassandra.

Best of luck!

Comment: I have one important requirement however: global geo-redundancy. Cassandra supports it out of the box, and multi master with RDBMS would have also problems like lost updates, or mixed updates.

Comment: True, but you can still lose data with Cassandra. If part of your quorum write fails, then your entire write fails. With an RDBMS, even if the update fails you still have the data in at least one location. See the PG wiki for some more detail on clustering postgres as an example of scaling an RDBMS: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: @FloppyDisk when your write consistency level in Cassandra can't be satisfied (ie you don't get a response from a quorum of nodes, if that's what you requested), the client gets an exception letting them know what happened.  Writes can be idempotent with Cassandra, so you can safely retry that write until it succeeds without worrying about overwriting new changes. No data loss involved.